# why won't my code update when I add a new Item to the list

Tags: forms, vue.js, methods

I am trying to allow an item to be pushed to a list of times that I looped through using Vue.js. I don't understand why when I click on the button the list item appears but the text doesn't.

### HTML

```html
 <div id="root">
    <input v-modle="newCat" v-on:keyup.enter="addKitty">
    <button v-on:click="addKitty">
      +add
    </button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="cat in cats">{{ cat.name }}</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

### Vue.js

```js
 app = new Vue({
   el: '#root',
   data: {
     cats: 
       [{name: 'kitkat'},
       { name: 'fish'},
       { name: 'henry'},
       { name: 'bosco'}],
     //new data set
     newCat: ''
   },
   methods: {
     addKitty: function() {
        this.cats.push({
         name: this.newCat
       })
      this.newCat = ''
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Always check your console for errors. This produces `[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: modle` due to your typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code.

```
<input v-modle="newCat" v-on:keyup.enter="addKitty">
```

Should be:

```
<input v-model="newCat" v-on:keyup.enter="addKitty">
```

Notice the different spelling for `v-model`.